# Who are the best commercial hosts of hidden services?

Tags: onion-services, web-hosting

I need a hosting company that:

1. Provides dedicated servers
2. Supports Tor hidden services
3. Supports Windows
4. Allows services to be paid for in Bitcoin
5. Has any other security bells and whistles I might find useful.

Does such a creature exist?

Comment: It is very difficult to justify hosting a hidden service using a third party provider unless you do not care about many of the benefits of using the Tor network. A server host will ultimately have control over your servers, and you obviously cannot guarantee privacy or security when a third party is managing your system. Your users' locations will be protected by the Tor network, but any data they provide will not be secure.

Comment: There are many similar questions. Maybe they should all be merged. I'm not risking any time on an answer until the dust settles ;)